# The shortest java code

Tags: java, short

```
import java.util.*;
public class SoSanh {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();
    if( a > b ) System.out.print("1");
    else if ( a < b ) System.out.print("-1");
    else System.out.print(0);               
}
}
```

How can I make this as small as possible. It had to be like 1-2 lines of code ( not including import,public class and main method )

This is not a homework, I learn Java through books and assignment on the internet. I just want to know if it can gets any shorter. It's not about Speed u guys are misunderstanding.

Sorry I'm very bad at English.

p/s : now I cannot ask any question :( there is only 1 more question I am facing with.

Comment: Why does it **have** to be 1-2 lines?

Comment: The shortness of the code does not in any way correlate with its speed. There is no way to make this code faster.

Comment: *Why* are 5 lines too long? The number of lines is not important for the speed of the code. The used algorithm is.

Comment: @Thomas No, I don't think any sane teacher would hand out such a perverted assignment. Fits into the category of silly job interview questions, though.

Comment: No this is not assignment, nobody teaches me Java, I am very very young , I learn Java by reading Books and a lot of them. I ask this so i could find a short code. I know that shortness of the code does not related to the speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Almost* correct:

```
System.out.println((int)Math.signum(input.nextInt() - input.nextInt());
```

"*Almost*" due to possible integer overlow. Also your longer code might actually be faster ([`signum()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29) operaton on floating-point numbers), not to mention more readable.

Comment: I just want to code to be SHORTER, it does not related the speed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that `Integer` is `Comparable`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(((Integer)input.nextInt()).compareTo(input.nextInt()));
```

Comment: Here is a [link to this code on ideone](http://ideone.com/daTfK).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of Tomasz's code without integer overflow problems:

```
System.out.println((int)Math.signum((double) input.nextInt() - (double) input.nextInt());
```

But yes, this is horrible.

Focus on readability, *not* "the shortest number of lines possible".

Answer (score 0):

2 lines that work:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(new Integer(input.nextInt()).compareTo(new Integer(input.nextInt())));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(Math.signum(input.nextInt() - input.nextInt()));
}
```